# How to Write this SQL with linq to sql

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Let's say I have a list with 2 or more customerIds and a list with two or more order dates. I want an SQL query like this from linq to sql

```
SELECT * 
FROM Orders 
WHERE (CustomerId = @CustomerId1 
       AND (OrderDate = @OrderDate1 OR OrderDate = @OrderDate2)) 
      OR
      (CustomerId = @CustomerId2 
       AND (OrderDate = @OrderDate1 OR OrderDate = @OrderDate2))
```

The list with CustomerIds and order dates is not fixed, so I need to loop through it when building the query.

Comment: You will have to add much more code and context if you expect any actual help

Comment: That would likely be better as `SELECT * FROM Orders where 
  CustomerId IN (@CustomerId1, @CustomerId2) AND OrderDate IN (@OrderDate1 , @OrderDate2)` - but yes please show your existing C# code.

Comment: This is just an example to illustrate what I need. What I need is a way to generate OR and AND conditions from multiple lists/arrays with information. It cannot be made into something like your example, like this link. from Order in Orders where ListWithOrders.Containts(Order.OrderId) && (Order.OrderDate == OrderDate1 || Order.OrderDate == OrderDate2)..

Comment: Yes there is. If you can show us your existing LINQ to SQL code we can give you some pointers.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this by using PredicateBuilder
from http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx